# Img/Audio Change by document.getElementByID("...").src=x+".png"; wont work

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, getelementbyid

I cant figure out why it is not working. Since its nothing too special I searched on the web - and here but all I found was either tutorials without the variable or questions with too specific questions.

Can anyone guide me on this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeaudio(x);
{

  document.getElementById("audioplayer").src=x+".mp3";
  document.getElementById("image").src=x+".png";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<img id="image" src="1.png">
<audio id="audioplayer" src="1.mp3" controls autoplay loop>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio> 
<br>

<input type="button" id="play" value="Play 1" onclick='changeaudio(1)"' />
<input type="button" id="play2" value="Play 2" onclick='changeaudio(2)"' />
<input type="button" id="play3" value="Play 3" onclick='changeaudio(3)"' />
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We're not here to "guide" you as we are not a discussion board. Please ask a concrete programming question (and make sure it will help someone else in future, too!) What does "not working" mean? What _does_ happen? What did you find out during debugging?

Comment: (Basic typos present in this code - please take more care before posting)

Comment: You're right. I'm will be more specific when I ask on here again in the future as well as spending more time with debugging. Hope its OK to ask: I tried debugging with Firefox but I coudnt get it to work. Can someone recommend a (simple, freeware) editor with a kind of a 'spelling check'? (Using Notepad++ atm)

Comment: Something tells me you didn't really understand what I said. :(

Comment: I really respect this site, its rules and its "codex". I don't understand why you think I didnt understand it. Please explain - In the comments someone recommanded me an Editor with syntax-error-"awareness. Thats not a duscussion, is it? Im sorry for the syntax-error-question. It really won't happen again. I thought my Problem was with variables in the function - I compared it to my book ('Head First JavaScript') and searched the Net but - since I already had the coding right (apart from the syntax) I thought it was a more complex thing I didn't understand. Pls tell me if I am wrong somehow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;` after your function definition: `function changeaudio(x);` should become:`function changeaudio(x)`

Also, your `onclick` syntax is wrong: `onclick='changeaudio(1)"'` should be: `onclick="changeaudio(1)"`.

Your final code should look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeaudio(x)
        {
            document.getElementById("audioplayer").src=x+".mp3";
            document.getElementById("image").src=x+".png";
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <img id="image" src="1.png" />
            <audio id="audioplayer" src="1.mp3" controls autoplay loop>
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio> 
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="play" value="Play 1" onclick="changeaudio(1)" />
            <input type="button" id="play2" value="Play 2" onclick="changeaudio(2)" />
            <input type="button" id="play3" value="Play 3" onclick="changeaudio(3)" />
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhk6Y/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer :) It works perfectly now. I rly gotta stop making stupid mistakes like that. I work with Notepad++ at the moment, do you happen to know a good freeware Editor who tells me about spelling errors?

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked for you. You might like to accept if it was useful.

Comment: (Edited the 1st comment)

Comment: + what do you mean with "accept"? Like a "thank you"-button or something? I couldnt find any.

Comment: Komodo Edit generally shows syntax errors. There should be a tick mark next to the answer, click on it.

Answer (score 0):

for a jquery approach :

```
$(function(){
    $('.play').each(function() {
       var mp3 = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $(this).click(function(){
           $('#audioplayer').attr("src", mp3+".mp3"); 
           $('#image').attr("src", mp3+".png"); 
        });
    });

});

 <center>
            <img id="image" src="1.png" />
            <audio id="audioplayer" src="1.mp3" controls autoplay loop>
            </audio> 
            <br />
            <input type="button" class="play" id="1" value="Play 1" />
            <input type="button" class="play" id="2" value="Play 2"  />
            <input type="button" class="play" id="3" value="Play 3" />
        </center>
```

**[jsFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QMQaA/)**

Comment: Why is the variable called `mp3`, even for images?

Comment: Why use jQuery for something **so** trivial?